# LibreOffice Tab Bar is positioned on top of the Toolbar

Tags: macos, open-office

I installed LibreOffice version 5.2.6.2 on my Mac.

Unfortunately, whenever I open a second document (or attempt to view the Properties of an open document) a Tab Bar appears, showing open documents.

This would be good, except the Tab Bar is positioned on top of the Toolbar, making it impossible to use.

I have noticed similar problems (overlapping dialogs) in other applications since upgrading to the last couple of versions of macOS.

Is there a app specific (or general) fix?

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Sierra 10.12.1 xxx

Comment: Same problem here.